# Probability Question using series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

There are $n$ dice with $f$ faces marked from $1$ to $f$, if these are thrown at random,what is the chance that the sum of the numbers exhibited shall be equal to $p$?

Please help me understand the first part of the solution - the number of ways in which the numbers thrown will have $p$ for their sum is equal to the coefficient of $x^p$ in the expansion $(x+x^2+x^3+..x^f)^n$. How does this work?

Also can you help me with a solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:-The landed dies will have 1 to f as their range of values. Imagine a gp such that 
(x^1........x^f)

now imagine n such gp

now multiply them

the coefficient of x^p in the final expansion is your answer.

Why?
because all possible outcomes are encapsulated in the sum for each coeff.

imagine die to be regular 1 to 6 at n=3 and p=7
one possibility is 1,3,3 i.e from x^1,x^3,x^3
and other permutations such as [331][313] etc will also have to be counted

Comment: think why x^0 is not included in the gp

Comment: Because 0 is not in the sample space ?

Comment: Yup its not on the die